# 'Port' aurelia-skeleton-navigation to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I've installed the aurelia-skeleton-navigation following [this guide](http://tutaurelia.net/2015/06/05/part-5-configuring-and-getting-started-with-aurelia/). However, I'd like to start using Typescript for my development. What would be the next correct step to get this going? I guess that simply changing the file-extensions to *.ts and compile using tsc will not be sufficient.

There are so many resources, but I always seem to run into trouble with one thing or another, every time I give it a shot.

Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.
I've pushed this to [github](https://github.com/nwinger/tutaurelia) - feel free to help out.

PS: I know there's a repository or two that has already done this, but I'd really like to at least understand the basics of how to port this to using typescript.

Comment: what is your IDE of choice?  what build strategy do you favor (gulp)?

Comment: @MikeGraham Atom or VS Code is fine. Gulp would also be fine :)

Comment: I've done it with VS Code, I don't remember it being particularly hard but the steps are a bit of a haze now... I'll have a look at my commits and see if I can make sense of what I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late, but I've done this and documented all the steps I took to move the skeleton project over to typescript here http://www.eriklieben.com/aurelia-skeleton-navigation-to-typescript/

Answer (score 4):

So here are some steps:

1. rename `.js` files to `.ts` files
2. setup gulp step to transpile your `.ts` files into `.js` files

   > take a look at this [gulp-typescript gulp task](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript-atom/blob/master/skel-nav-ts/gulpfile.js#L7-L27) as a reference

Note: you will want to include `paths` in your gulp step above to the `.d.ts` files that are found in each [aurelia](http://aurelia.io) repository's `dist` folder.  The path will look something like: `jspm_packages/github/aurelia/*/dist/*.d.ts`

Also tricky: for `fetch-client` you may also need to include a `path` to the `whatwg-fetch.d.ts` type definition (found in `fetch-client/doc`)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In step 1, do you mean all .js files including all sub-folders containing various combinations of *.js? (Suchs as map files etc.)
Is there a clever way of doing that recursively when in the root folder?

Comment: you can do the renaming from a bash script.  i'll find that for your tomorrow.  you can ignore or delete the .map files since they will be generated by the typescript compiler during transpilation